# How do I check the stability of multiple beta versions of software that all needs to build together?

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, build, build-system

My team is developing an iOS app with ARKit in Unity. Until the release date in September, we have to rely on beta versions of Xcode, iOS 11, Unity, and the Unity ARKit plugin. We lost almost a day of development time trying to figure out what was breaking, which turned out to be these beta version issues.

I want to be able to know what combinations of different versions of each system work so we can quickly identify issues. For example, something that says "the ARKit sample app from Xcode 9 beta 2 builds with Xcode 9 beta 4 but not vice versa" and "the Unity ARKit sample app does not build with version 2 of the plugin and and Xcode 9 beta 4."

I've heard tools like Jenkins or Travis mentioned but I don't know what they do or how they get put together.

We're a team of four college students with no industry experience beyond internships, so perhaps that's relevant to making sure this isn't an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

[Lastly, apologies if this is not the right forum for the question. I'd be happy to close this and post somewhere else.]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's the nature of the beast when using beta tools and API's. Things will break and change. You are on the *bleeding edge* as they say, so when you experience an incompatibility you may very well be the very first person to 'uncover' it. Be sure to file bug reports as you discover those and be active on forums and communities as much as possible.

Your best source of information is from the vendors themselves. Release notes specifically are a valuable piece of information. For Xcode and Apple technologies, go over to the downloads section of the [developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/download/) and read the release notes of the relevant tools and platforms:
[image: downloads section Apple developer portal]

Take a look at the known issues:

[image: known issues Xcode]

Same thing for [Unity](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-2017.1.0) or any other tools:

[image: known issues Unity]

I'm not sure how build tools such as Jenkins will help you out. You might be able to set-up a working build pipeline with specific versions of the tools in question. But seeing as how these tools and API's are in constant flux (and this stage, for good reasons of course) those pipelines might get deprecated very quickly...

Comment: Really, the only thing I want to avoid is being surprised that something doesn't build. I'm OK with things not building - as you said, that comes with the territory of being on the bleeding edge. I do want to know that we as a team should have a smaller goal two days from now because such and such build system requires updates that may break our build.

Comment: So it's the vision of having ten or twelve different pipelines, and either some notification system or automatic process that notices there are different or newly available tools, and an easy [~1h] way to add in the latest version to the mix.